# ListView in fragment

Tags: android-studio

Buenas tardes, alguna ayuda de como utilizar listView en un fragment ? He visto muchos tutoriales pero sinceramente son de versiones anteriores y con la ultima version del Android Studio no me corren ciertas sintaxis, agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que te hace falta añadir el siguiente import que es este:
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
Ademas en el onCreateView debes declarar una variable de tipo View por ejemplo

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);


ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_contact);

return rootView;
```

}

Espero que te Sirva.
Saludos